# longest distance between these two or more points

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a program that takes two different points, A(x1,y1) and B(x2,y2) and returns the distance between these two points. The distance formula is Pythagorean Theorem.

```
import math

def get_dist(point):
    return math, sqrt((points[0]-points[2])**2 + (points[1]-points[3])**2)
```

Comment: Where is `points` defined? Your parameter is `point`

Comment: Also see [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: This code has several errors with rather self-explanatory exceptions. After fixing them, what *specific* problem do you need help with?

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3.7 or lower

If you are using python 3.7 or lower you can use the built-in function `math.hypot` that uses the Pythagorean Theorem. Then you could define a function as follows:

```py
import math


def get_dist(point_a, point_b):
    x1, y1 = point_a
    x2, y2 = point_b
    return math.hypot(x1-x2, y1-y2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = (1, 1)
    b = (-3, 4)
    print('get_dist(a, b):', get_dist(a, b))
```

## Python 3.8

As mentioned in a comment if you are using python 3.8 you can directly use the `math.dist` function without needing to implement anything yourself as I did above.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Funny how you say "Python already has a built-in function ..." and then don't use `math.dist`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have to be more ordered, for example your function calculates the distance of two points, so your inpunts are 2 variables, and each variable is an orderer pair:

```
import math

def get_dist(point_1:tuple, point_2:tuple):
    return math.sqrt((point_1[0]-point_2[0])**2 + (point_1[1]-point_2[1])**2)
```